# Xelatex does not handle tabs correctly when writting to a file

Tags: xetex, symbols

When using the `xsimverb` package, I can easily write something to a file. Problem: if I use `xelatex` to compile, I get tabs replaced with `^^I` in the file, while lualatex and pdflatex preserve the tabs as expected (this is truly written in the file, this is not an artifact of `\verbatiminput`):

[image]

Any idea how to solve this?

MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xsimverb}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{TestEnv}{sm}{%
  \XSIMfilewritestart{\jobname-robExt-tmp-file-you-can-remove.tmp}%
}{%
  \XSIMfilewritestop%
  \verbatiminput{\jobname-robExt-tmp-file-you-can-remove.tmp}%
}%

\begin{TestEnv}{test}
  This is a test with 2 tabs precisely here >>      <<.
\end{TestEnv}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

Seems like `xelatex -8bit foo.tex` solves this error… but not sure if there is a cleaner solution. Also, some of my users seem to still have issues even with `-8bit`.

Comment: The strategy is very simple: never use TAB when dealing with TeX. Reserve the TAB key to trigger autocompletion and your life will be happier.

Comment: @egreg Ahah, I do use spaces myself, but seems like TexStudio actually use Tabs, and my users then report bugs thinking that it was because of my library ^^